# Disable tap to click without Precision touchpad on 7+ Year old Laptop - no proper drivers for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I need to disable tap to click on a laptop that no longer has specific drivers to give tap to click option - just sensitivity.

The laptop is 7+ years old. Originally with windows 7 samsung had a driver with this tap to click option. I've contacted samsung since and there is no driver for windows 10 which I've now upgraded to.

When I've ran linux I can disable tap-to-click still. So surely it's possible and hopefully easy enough with windows 10 ?

The only options I have are for mouse sensitity right now.

I'm forever catching the trackpad and need windows for some applications I use.

Comment: Did you try installing the W7 driver?

Comment: Search the Registry under HKCU\Software\<manufacturer name> for "tap_to_activate", "tap_enable", etc. and set any "activate" or "_enable" to 0, and any "_disable" to 1. This depends on the touchpad manufacturer, q.v.

Comment: Installing the original windows 7 driver for the touchpad from samsung's own website for my particulary model of laptop worked perfectly. I hadn't realised it would work just as well as it did under windows 7. It gave me ALL the options for a precision touchpad then. I had a box to uncheck to turn off the annoying tap to click which I am always catching and selecting/left clicking by accident. The options for two fingered scroll, pinch to zoom etc were all there too. (I started to search the registry for the options mentioned but couldn't quickly find them so abandonned looking.)